# trigger CountUp function when element comes into view

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using this library

https://github.com/inorganik/ngx-countUp

is there A way to activate the counting animation only when reach the section of numbers

in another words to trigger it (`<h1 [countUp]="345">0</h1>`) when element is scrolled into view

is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbehe9) `Viewchild` is a way for this.

in html make value as parametric.

```
<h1 #counter [countUp]="param">0</h1>
```

in component

```
@ViewChild('counter') counter: ElementRef;
param=0;
```

with hostlistener listen scroll and check if if scroll reach to html if yes change count to 365

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) // for window scroll events
onWindowScroll(event) {
   var rect = this.counter.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
   var elemTop = rect.top; var elemBottom = rect.bottom;
   (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight) ? this.param=365:null
}
```